# How to make a notification to the dynamic cell phone with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, notifications

I made my code where an administrator can send a message to a group, and soon all users within that group receive notification on the mobile app:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    if(!($error = $this->isNotValidate($request))){
        //Log::error(print_r("validado", true));

        $message = Message::create($request->toArray());

        $message->recives()->attach($request->recive_ids);

        foreach($message->recives as $group){
            foreach($group->users as $user){
                $user->notify(new NotificationMessage($message));
            }
        }

        $response = ['message' => $message];
        return response($response, 200);
    }
    return response($error, 422);
}
```

I used the library: https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/fcm it is working he send the notification to the mobile through the firebase.

my difficulty is that in the toFcm function I want to retrieve the message to build the notification I'm sending:

```
public function toFcm($notifiable)
{
    return FcmMessage::create()
        ->setData(['message_id' => $this->invoice->id, 'message_created' => $this->invoice->created_at])
        ->setNotification(\NotificationChannels\Fcm\Resources\Notification::create()
            ->setTitle($this->invoice->title)
            ->setBody($this->invoice->content)
            //->setImage('http://example.com/url-to-image-here.png')
        )->setAndroid(
            AndroidConfig::create()
                ->setFcmOptions(AndroidFcmOptions::create()->setAnalyticsLabel('analytics'))
                ->setNotification(AndroidNotification::create()->setColor('#0A0A0A'))
        )->setApns(
            ApnsConfig::create()
                ->setFcmOptions(ApnsFcmOptions::create()->setAnalyticsLabel('analytics_ios')));
}
```

I thought that in the variable `$this->invoice` or in the `$notifiable` would come the `$message` that I am passing as a parameter in the creation, but it does not pass, both are returning the user.

does anyone know how i can make this dynamic notification with my message data?

**UPDATE**

```
class NotificationMessage extends Notification
{
    /**
     * Specifies the user's FCM token
     *
     * @return string|array
     */
    public function routeNotificationForFcm()
    {
        return $this->fcm_token;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [FcmChannel::class];
    }

    public function toFcm($notifiable)
    {
        return FcmMessage::create()
            ->setData(['message_id' => $notifiable->id, 'message_created' => $notifiable->created_at])
            ->setNotification(\NotificationChannels\Fcm\Resources\Notification::create()
                ->setTitle($notifiable->title)
                ->setBody($notifiable->content)
                //->setImage('http://example.com/url-to-image-here.png')
            )->setAndroid(
                AndroidConfig::create()
                    ->setFcmOptions(AndroidFcmOptions::create()->setAnalyticsLabel('analytics'))
                    ->setNotification(AndroidNotification::create()->setColor('#0A0A0A'))
            )->setApns(
                ApnsConfig::create()
                    ->setFcmOptions(ApnsFcmOptions::create()->setAnalyticsLabel('analytics_ios')));
    }

    // optional method when using kreait/laravel-firebase:^3.0, this method can be omitted, defaults to the default project
    public function fcmProject($notifiable, $message)
    {
        // $message is what is returned by `toFcm`
        return 'app'; // name of the firebase project to use
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the __construct function of the notification so we can check what happens with the message you pass? It's unclear what happens with the message now, and it is unclear where the invoice is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to invert the logic of who was my notify, now instead of the user being the notify, my message became

In my control I'm even simpler:

```
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        if(!($error = $this->isNotValidate($request))){
            //Log::error(print_r("validado", true));

            $message = Message::create($request->toArray());

            $message->recives()->attach($request->recive_ids);

            $message->notify(new NotificationMessage);

            $response = ['message' => $message];
            return response($response, 200);
        }
        return response($error, 422);
    }
```

in my message template I made the following changes:

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
...

class Message extends BaseModel
{
    use Notifiable;
    ...
    public function routeNotificationForFcm()
    {
        $tokens = [];
        foreach($this->recives as $group){
            foreach($group->users as $user){
                $tokens = array_merge($tokens, $user->notifications()->pluck('token')->toArray());
            }
        }
        return $tokens;
    }
}
```

with that in my variable `$notifiable` started to receive the information of the message and then it was easy to pass them as parameter.